# MVC accessing linked table value using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and I am trying to get my head around it.  I am used to writing stored procedures which have all the data I need on a example by example basis.

I am under the impression that I can get all values from a particular table including the foreign key values direct using entity framework without having to write a select query which joins the data.

I have the following in my controller

```
    public ActionResult Patient()
    {
        using (var context = new WaysToWellnessDB())
        {
            var patients = context.Patients.ToList();
            return View(patients);
        }
    }
```

In my view I have the following

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>
        @item.FirstName @item.Surname @item.Gender.GenderDesc
    </p>
}
```

I have two tables, Patient and Gender, GenderId is a foreign key which I am trying to get the GenderDesc from that table.

I am getting the following message

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Can someone explain why I cannot access GenderDesc.  It does work if I remove the using() around my context, but I don't really want to leave that open, is there a way to get this to work still having the using around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you have disposed of the context as it is within a using statement, so anything you try to access from then on will not be able to be lazy loaded. The disadvantage with lazy loading is that it will perform a query for the gender for every patient you are iterating over, which is handy, but bad! I would load the related table at query time using Include.

You'll need a new import:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

And then include the related table:

```
var patients = context.Patients.Include(p => p.Gender).ToList();
```

That will result in a query which will join to your "Gender" table and you should be able to output `item.Gender.GenderDesc` in your view.